# Elastic Search multi word synonyms not working as I'd expected

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I have an ElasticSearch search engine and I'm adding synonyms support to it. Everything goes well for unigram synonyms but it's all messed up when starting to deal with multi-words synonyms.

For example, I want the following query - "ice cream" to return each document that talks about "ice cream" or "gelato" or "icecream".

My mapping settings are as follows

```
PUT stam_test_1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "plural_stemmer": {
          "name": "minimal_english",
          "type": "stemmer"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        },
        "english_graph_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "expand": true,
          "synonyms": [
            "ice cream, icecream, creamery, gelato",
            "dim sum, dim sim, dimsim",
            "ube, purple yam",
            "sf, san francisco"
          ]
        },
        "english_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "expand": true,
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "synonyms": [
            "burger, hamburger, slider",
            "chicken, pollo",
            "pork, pig, porc",
            "barbeque, bbq, barbecue",
            "sauce, dressing"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "plural_stemmer",
            "english_stop",
            "english_stemmer",
            "asciifolding",
            "english_synonyms"
          ]
        },
        "english_search": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "plural_stemmer",
            "english_stop",
            "english_stemmer",
            "asciifolding",
            "english_graph_synonyms"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "post_text": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "english",
            "search_analyzer": "english_search"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm adding a few documents

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "stam_test_1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "post_text" : "Love this ice cream so much!!!"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "stam_test_1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "post_text" : "Great gelato and a tasty burger"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "stam_test_1",  "_id" : "3" } }
{ "post_text" : "I bought coke but did not get any ice with it" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "stam_test_1", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "post_text" : "ic cream" }
```

When I'm querying for "ice cream" 
GET /stam_test_1/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "post_text": {
        "query": "ice cream",
        "analyzer": "english_search"}
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following results

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.6678555,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "stam_test_1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : 2.6678555,
        "_source" : {
          "post_text" : "ic cream"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "stam_test_1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "post_text" : "Great gelato and a tasty burger"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see that intentionally I've added an already stemmed document - "ic cream" that returned as I suspected while I didn't get the first document "Love this ice cream so much!!!".

When I'm directly testing the analyzer on "ice cream"

```
GET stam_test_1/_analyze?
{
  "analyzer": "english_search",
  "text" : "ice cream"
}
```

It returns

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "icecream",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "softserv",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "icream",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "creameri",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "gelato",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "ic",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "cream",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The uni-word synonyms are returning properly but the multi-words are stemmed (each token, separately) and it seems that the actual document is not stemmed (this is why I got the 'ic cream' document).

I'm sure this is simply the definition of a setting that went wrong. I tried to replace the english_search analyzer's tokenizer with "keyword" instead of "standard" but no luck with that as well.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem? The synonyms_graph feature has a really minor amount of documentation and Google results.

Comment: The multiword are stemmed cause you are set the analyzer in that way. Have you tried to put the "english_graph_synonyms" not as the final filter but only after lowercase in analyzer definition inside mapping?

Comment: @Lupanoide I did and still not works for me. The problem is that the query "ice creaming (let's pretend there's such word) won't be recognized as a synonym.

Comment: And that is correct cause now the synonyms are generated before stemming. It returns ic cream because you are making a match query that tokenize your search text. So it search for stems generated from tokens: ice and cream. If you don't want ic cream you could try this that I can't verify now : { "query": { "match": { "post_text": { "query": "ice cream", "search_analyzer": "keyword"} } } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my mistake was the mappings definition. I shouldn't define fields, all I had to do is using the following mappings and it's all working properly this way

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "post_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english",
        "search_analyzer": "english_search"
      }
    }
  }
```